# react-native tabbar bottom hides a component

Tags: react-native

I am building a profile page and have the following components.
1. I have a image picker for the profile picture
2. ListView with text fields and a button

And i have a bottom bar navigation. With the current implementation the bottom tab bar hides the button at the bottom, and i am not able to figure out a way to solve this. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code snippet,

```
     render(){
    let {phone} = this.state,
     {studentName}=this.state,
     {studentClass}=this.state,
     {bloodGroup}=this.state,
     {parentName}=this.state,
     {email}=this.state,
     {sibling}=this.state,
     {siblingClass}=this.state,
     {address}=this.state;

    return(
        <View style={styles.studentInfo}>

            <TextField 
            label='Student Name'
            value={studentName}
            onChangeText={(studentName)=>this.setState({studentName})}
            />

             <TextField 
                label='Class'
                value={studentClass}
                onChangeText={(studentClass)=>this.setState({studentClass})}
            />

            <TextField 
                label='Blood Group'
                value={bloodGroup}
                onChangeText={(bloodGroup)=>this.setState({bloodGroup})}
            />

            <TextField 
                label='Parent Name'
                value={parentName}
                onChangeText={(parentName)=>this.setState({parentName})}
            />

            <TextField 
                label='Phone Number'
                value={phone}
                onChangeText={(phone)=>this.setState({phone})}
            />

            <TextField 
                label='E mail'
                value={email}
                onChangeText={(email)=>this.setState({email})}
            />

            <TextField 
                label='Sibling Studying in the school'
                value={sibling}
                onChangeText={(sibling)=>this.setState({sibling})}
            />

            <TextField 
                label='Class'
                value={siblingClass}
                onChangeText={(siblingClass)=>this.setState({siblingClass})}
            />

            <TextField 
                label='Address'
                value={address}
                onChangeText={(address)=>this.setState({address})}
            />

             <Button 
                style={{backgroundColor: '#3e9cd3'}} 
                textStyle={{fontSize: 18}}
                onPress={()=> this.handleButtonPress()}>
                Save
            </Button>
         </View>
    );
}
```

[image: As you can see that the button is hidden behind the tabbar bottom component]

Comment: Why don't you use `ScrollView` instead of `View` that is wrapping your `TextField` and `Button`?

Comment: @AhsanAli: Tried that with no success. :(

Comment: which react native tab bar you are using? Is it react-native-tabbar-bottom?

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi: Yes!